# Toast not showing on caller screen on Huawei

Tags: android, android-toast, huawei-mobile-services

When incoming call is received I show toast. This is working when call is coming and device is not locked. But when device is locked and receiving incoming call toast is not showing. This only happens on Huawei devices, Samsung devices are okay, show toast on incoming call no matter devices is locked or not.

How can I achieve to show toast on Huawei devices also?

Comment: Nothing to do with API version? Also: consider using alert messages instead toast.

Comment: For alert messages user needs to gave permission to draw over other apps, that is not solution for me. It seams that toast is created but it is under caller screen if call received when device was locked, when was unlocked toast shows normally. Any way to bring toast to front?